# Robotium - Start another activity from main activity

Tags: android, robotium

I want to test an android app.
The framework I chose was Robotium and I was able to write test cases that involved using single activity with(out) fragments.

My problem is now I have my activity under test as activityA.
From activityA, I want to disable some fields (which i was able to do) and then start activityB.
How can this be done?

Comment: You need yo show us some of your code... Put yourself in our shoes: how would we help without any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to start another activity use:

```
Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
startActivity(i); //Start Activity B
finish(); //Close Activity A
```

Comment: thanks.
I knew this but somehow was always missing it.
thanks a lot